# geth: can not resend transaction - transaction not found

Tags: go-ethereum

I'm trying to resend a transaction unrecognized by network with increased gas price:

```
tx = eth.pendingTransactions[0]
eth.resend(tx, web3.toWei(0.5, "szabo"))
```

What I'm getting is:

```
Transaction 0x1c6f5e5ffd2109167fa2bad731224d5e5b3cec8a654debffaa665bdc12969020 not found
at web3.js:3119:20
at web3.js:6023:15
at web3.js:4995:36
at <anonymous>:1:1
```

What's wrong?

Comment: maybe it was commited to a block already?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Did you ever find out what was wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Running this patch at the console works for me:

```
eth.resend = function (tx, gasPrice, gas) {
  if (gasPrice) {
    tx.gasPrice = gasPrice;
  }
  if (gas) {
    tx.gas = gas;
  }
  tx.data = tx.input;
  return eth.sendTransaction(tx);
};
```

I prefer to also add this convenience version:

```
eth.resendgwei = function (tx, gasPriceInGwei, gas) {
  if (gasPriceInGwei) {
    return eth.resend(tx, web3.toWei(gasPriceInGwei, 'gwei'), gas);
  }
  else {
    return eth.resend(tx, null, gas);
  }
};
```

Now, if your pending transaction is stuck because the gas price is too low, you can speed it up with:

```
eth.resendgwei(eth.pendingTransactions[0], 51);
```