# geth transactions stuck in pending, resend fails

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, pending-transactions

I sent 115 transactions with geth, and they are stuck in pending for over an hour. Etherscan doesn't recognize them. I try to resend, and get a confusing error. Some details from geth console:

```
> eth.pendingTransactions.length
115

> eth.resend(eth.pendingTransactions[0], web3.toWei(20, 'gwei'))
Error: Transaction a075b95c7242178330ae22373a1138e9ec22cbd9dd54964980fc1a36182acdbe not found
    at web3.js:3104:20
    at web3.js:6191:15
    at web3.js:5004:36
    at <anonymous>:1:1

> eth.pendingTransactions[0].hash == "0xa075b95c7242178330ae22373a1138e9ec22cbd9dd54964980fc1a36182acdbe"
false
```

The [eth.resend docs](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/JavaScript-Console#ethresend) don't offer much more help.

This might be a duplicate of: [geth: can not resend transaction - transaction not found](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/9374/geth-can-not-resend-transaction-transaction-not-found)

---

*Edit: fixed code typo in the writeup (but typo was not in the console).

Interestingly, the pool did eventually clear out on its own, after 24 hours, and all the transactions were successfully sent. But the question about why `eth.resend()` was failing still stands. (or perhaps clarification on the purpose of the function)

Comment: You have a stray `)` in your second line. Other then that, how did you create the transaction? Can you post the entire tx? Which version of `geth`?

Comment: geth 1.6.1-stable -- The transactions did eventually clear out, they just took much longer than I expected. I was using a 2 Gwei gas price, and it took 24 hours for the transactions to send. There was 0 progress for hours at a time, then a few would go through. I would love to learn more about how peers handle big transaction pools, but for now, I'm just rate-limiting myself to only a handful of pending transactions at a time.

Comment: For posterity: the network had a spike of transactions. Search discussions around 2017-05-30 -- 2017-06-01, relating to the BAT ICO, Poloniex per-user accounts, etc..

Comment: The issue was reproducible on other dates, when transaction count was low.

Comment: This returns `Error: intrinsic gas too low`. I was not able to fix it :( @carver

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I still don't know why `eth.resend` was failing (and continues to fail as of geth 1.6.5), but this compatible patch works for me:

```
eth.resend = function (tx, gasPrice, gas) {
  if (gasPrice) {
    tx.gasPrice = gasPrice;
  }
  if (gas) {
    tx.gas = gas;
  }
  tx.data = tx.input;
  return eth.sendTransaction(tx);
};
```

I prefer to also add this convenience version:

```
eth.resendgwei = function (tx, gasPriceInGwei, gas) {
  if (gasPriceInGwei) {
    return eth.resend(tx, web3.toWei(gasPriceInGwei, 'gwei'), gas);
  }
  else {
    return eth.resend(tx, null, gas);
  }
};
```

Now, if your pending transaction is stuck because the gas price is too low, you can speed it up with:

```
eth.resendgwei(eth.pendingTransactions[0], 27);
```

Comment: I am having `Error: intrinsic gas too low` or `Error: replacement transaction underpriced error.` @carver

Comment: It means your gas price is too low.

Comment: I know that `gasPrice` is too low! There was a small issue on `geth` side, its fixed as follows: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/16284 @carver