# Transaction having low gasPrice makes all the other transactions hang on the pending state

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, pending-transactions

I have a small private network that has a proof-of-authority engine created via `geth-clique` using `Geth Version: 1.8.3-unstable`, currently there are three signer nodes and two other non-signer nodes (lets call them `peer-A` and `peer-B`). `peer-A` and `peer-B` are connected to three signer nodes.

First, I sent a transaction with very low `gasPrice` such as 200, on `peer-A` as shown below.

```
eth.sendTransaction({from:eth.accounts[0], to:eth.accounts[1], value: web3.toWei(0,0000, "ether"), gasPrice: 200})
```

Later when I sent more transactions on `peer-A` even with greater `gasPrice`, all of those transactions will remain on the pending state. As I understand submitted transactions work as FIFO queue and my upcoming transactions are stuck 
since the first send transaction with very low `gasPrice` locks others.

Example: (First `peer-A` and `peer-B` sent a Tx with low `gasPrice` and later their other Tx with high gasPrice stuck on their pending state.)
[image]

I have fix this situation by cleaning my `chaindata` on `peer-A`, which also cleans all pending transactions: `rm -rf private/geth`, and later I send my transactions with larger `gasPrice`. I assume this was a very inefficient solution for networks has a large chain.

So all sent transactions are provided as FIFO queue? Why not they selected based on which has the highest `gasPrice`?

Please note that I have tried:

```
eth.resend(eth.pendingTransactions[0], web3.toWei(1000, 'gwei'))
```

but faced with following error:

`Error: intrinsic gas too low` or `Error: replacement transaction underpriced error.`

**[Q]** How could I solve this problem, how could I remove the pending transaction on the system which has a low gasPrice or reject them or update their `gasPrice` value and `resend()` them?

Github issue: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/16284

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Péter Szilágyi's answer on (https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/16284) help me to solve the problem.

> Every account and transaction in Ethereum has a nonce. At any given
>   time, only the transaction with the correct nonce can be executed. If
>   you submit a transaction with a low gas price, that will block all
>   subsequent transactions since they are not executable nonce wise, only
>   the next nonce is executable.
>
> You don't need to clear your chain data folder, pending transactions
>   are not stored there. There's a transactions.rlp file which saves the
>   local transactions.

I was using `eth.resend()` with two parameters.

**=>** Adding `gasLimit` as third parameter solved it, example:

```
eth.resend(eth.pendingTransactions[0], web3.toWei(20, 'gwei'), 2000000)
```

**=>** Or stop the node,  remove `transactions.rlp` file (`rm ~/examplePOA/private/geth/transactions.rlp`) and restart.

Answer (score 1):

An easier solution (comparing to reseting the chain) is to send a replacement transaction that

- has the same account nonce (more info [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/27432/20451)) as the pending low gas transaction
- offers higher gas price

For a efficient algorithm regarding the more generic issue of nonce singleton, see [this question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/39790/20451) and its answers.

Comment: I have tried to offer higher gas price by following (https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/18154/4575), but I have faced with some errors. @Linmao Song

Comment: Any errors from the web3, or Geth/Parity log, for the replacement transaction?

Comment: I am having `Error: intrinsic gas too low` or `Error: replacement transaction underpriced error.`@Linmao Song

Comment: Could it be the replacement transaction's gas price is still too low? How does the new gas price compare to the old price, also to the average gas price (e.g. web3.eth.gasPrice)?

Comment: `web3.eth.gasPrice is 18000000000`, I have tried: `eth.resend(eth.pendingTransactions[0], web3.toWei(1000, 'gwei'))` but still the same error. @Linmao Song