# Does sendRawTransaction behave the same as sendTransaction with nonce parameter.

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, nonce

In the Javascript API wiki it states that if you send a transaction with sendTransaction() and the optional nonce parameter set you can overwrite your pending transaction.

> nonce: Number - (optional) Integer of a nonce. This allows to overwrite your own pending transactions that use the same nonce.

In my code I am using sendRawTransaction() and if I set the nonce to the same as my last tx while it is still pending it bounces and never gets accepted to the pool. Is this what should be expected for sendRawTransaction?

I am re-signing the transaction each time with the same/previous nonce. I get a txid returned but after many attempts it has never overwritten the tx and I can never get working txid.

Is this the expected behavior?

I am having trouble using web3.eth.pendingTransactions it always returns an empty array. So i cant use eth.resend(web3.eth.pendingTransactions[0], newGasPrice). Ultimately my goal is to overwrite a transactions with a higher gas price when certain conditions are met.

Comment: Yes, if you use sendRawTransaction with a higher fee it should replace a pending transaction. In geth the default increase should be above 10% of the price. Also you do not have a guarantee that it will replaced, it can be already mined when you send the replacement. Does your transaction appear in `txpool` output?

Comment: In a well-functioning node, `web3.eth.pendingTransactions` shouldn't be empty if you sent a transaction that hasn't been mined yet. That seems like the problem you need to solve first. BTW, if you get that solved, look out for a different issue with `resend()`: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/9374/geth-can-not-resend-transaction-transaction-not-found/18541#18541

Comment: @carver
If I run web3.eth.pendingTransactions I get: "[]" 
However when i run txpool i get a very big output of txs.... and status: {
    pending: 3987,
    queued: 18
  },

Comment: @Ismael I attempted to send the tx again at least a dozen times only moments after the first. I could see my first tx on https://etherscan.io/txsPending?a=MyAddressHere and never would the later sent txs show up here despite getting a txid for them I would assume my tx was still in the txpool. My gas price was considerably higher each time.

Comment: Does web3.eth.pendingTransactions require any prequisites? I assumed it was transactions that were sent from that node.

Comment: web3.eth.pendingTransactions should work out-of-the-box (are you using geth?). What happens when you run `eth.getTransaction(txid)` on the txid for the previous and replacement transaction? This will show `{blockNumber: null ... }` if the transaction is pending.

Comment: @carver I am using geth. I have done some further testing/research and it seems I am getting confused by the naming. I assumed web3 was the same as web3.js or the javascript API (that you run in the browser) If i send a transaction from my geth console i do get values returned by web3.eth.pendingTransactions in the console but if i send them from my browser they dont come up in the console and the Javascript API has no resend function so even if i can get an object that resembles that which comes from the pendingTransaction it will be of no use.

Comment: And web3.eth.pendingTransactions comes up as undefined in the browser.

Comment: I think it would help to start from the beginning, and write out exactly the code you're running, and in what context. Copy in the output you're seeing, and tell us what you were expecting instead. BTW, `resend()` is just a convenience function on top of `sendTransaction()`. I reimplemented an example resend in the question I linked to above.