# Why are the sent time of these transactions constantly reset and why are they still pending after 14 hours?

Tags: transactions, metamask, pending-transactions

Why are the sent time of these transactions constantly reset and why are they still pending after 14 hours?

Hello,

Yesterday I tried to send some test transactions from Metamask. One with 0.01 Gwei and one with 5 Gwei gas price. When I check on etherscan the sent time is constantly reset. So even today it still looks like they were sent five minutes ago or so. Also, they just keep pending, they never actually arrive in the other account.

https://etherscan.io/address/0x00c101e88d7f1382874d1a0013621479ed148933

What's wrong and how can it be rectified?

Vesa

Comment: A geth console way of fixing the problem is described in this question https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/9374/geth-can-not-resend-transaction-transaction-not-found

Answer (score 1):

This is happenning when transaction fee is too low. I think etherscan dropping transaction from mempool after sometime, if it is not confirmed. Because of transaction still in the network it is coming back to etherscan.  You need to resend these txs with same nonce value but higher gas price. This way your transactions will replaced with new one. The important part is nonce value needs to be same.

You can find detailed explanation in this link

https://myetherwallet.github.io/knowledge-base/transactions/check-status-of-ethereum-transaction.html

Comment: I check the recommended low gas price at https://www.ethgasstation.info before sending and then it was five Gwei. I checked again now and noticed it has gone up to ten Gwei. I guess that could be the reason. If I want to resend the same transactions, how do I use the same nonce?